# how to get all the rows present in table using sql query where year is a leap year

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
MovieID int PRIMARY KEY,
year int,
rank int);

INSERT INTO Movie (MovieID, year, rank, ...)
VALUES (1, 1888, 4)
VALUES (2, 1889, 4)
VALUES (3, 1890, 5)
VALUES (4, 1900, 3)
VALUES (5, 1905, 4)
VALUES (6, 1947, 2)
VALUES (7, 1976, 1)
VALUES (8, 2000, 4);
```

now i want to fetch all the row where year is a leap year?

Answer (score 3):

Use this query. A leap year feb month has 29 days.

```
select * 
from Movie where DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY,31,DATEADD(YEAR,@YEAR-1900,0)))) = 29
```

Comment: Unexpected approach. Interesting.

Comment: @ zip Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * from Movie where year(EOMONTH(DATEADD(year,31,DATEADD(year,@YEAR-1900,0)))) = 29 ': no such function: DATEADD

Comment: Ok, what sql plateform are you using? I need that to use the DATEADD function of that plateform

Comment: @zip i am using sqlite3 to make connection with my database(.db file) then using pandas to run SQL query like pd.read_sql_query.

Answer (score 3):

> i am using sqlite3

```
WHERE strftime('%d', year || '-03-01', '-1 day') = '29'
```

Comment: @forpas Oh, thanks! I always forget this SQLite feature.

Answer (score 2):

Boring arithmetic:

MySQL:

```
SELECT *
WHERE MOD(`year`,4) = 0 AND MOD(`year`, 100) != 0 OR MOD(`year`, 400) = 0
```

SQLite (standard modulo operator):

```
SELECT *
WHERE year % 4 = 0 AND year %100 != 0 OR `year`% 400 = 0
```

Modulo (`%`) would've worked for MySQL as well, but I thought that explicit MOD function would be easier on eyes.

Comment: it is giving error as Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * from Movie WHERE MOD(`year`,4) = 0 AND MOD(`year`, 100) != 0 OR MOD(`year`, 400) = 0 ': no such function: MOD

Comment: yes arithmetic is boring but i am learning sql so i don't know how to write a query involving arithmetic operation

Comment: You had MySQL before and I used its syntax.

Comment: Added the code that will work on SQLite (assuming no typos).